# Behat not autoloading additional classes to a test context

Tags: php, behat

**Behat version 3.0.12, PHP 5.3.3**

I'll describe the problem before showing my setup: I'm creating a small test Behat project, but when I try and create additional classes in other files to pull into my context file, Behat doesn't autoload them. The docs say that anything in `features/bootstrap` should be autoloaded and available. The specific error is this:

```
Fatal error: Class 'TestObject' not found in /data/drupal7/sites/behat-test/projects/test-project/features/bootstrap/TestContext.php on line 23
```

In the [version 3 docs](http://docs.behat.org/en/v3.0/quick_intro_pt1.html), the tutorial defines a class in a new PHP file and brings it in effortlessly. Trying to do the same on my version doesn't work.

I've got a Behat setup like this:

```
composer.*
projects
vendor
```

This is a standard result of installing Behat, except there's a new folder where my individual projects have their own folder in `project/<project name>`. For instance, `project/test_project`:

```
behat.yml
features
    |-- test.feature
    |-- bootstrap
           |-- TestContext.php
           |-- Test.php
```

My config file, `behat.yml` looks like this:

```
default:
    suites:
        default:
            paths:     [ %paths.base%/features ]
            bootstrap: [ $paths.features%/bootstrap ]
            contexts:  [ TestContext ]
```

The `TestContext.php` looks like this:

```
<?php

use Behat\Behat\Tester\Exception\PendingException;
use Behat\Behat\Context\Context;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\PyStringNode;
use Behat\Gherkin\Node\TableNode;

/**
 * Behat context class.
 */
class TestContext implements Context
{
    private $test;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->test = new TestObject();
    }

    /**
     * @Given I go to the Google homepage
     */
    public function iGoToTheGoogleHomepage()
    {
        throw new PendingException();
    }
}
```

And finally, `Test.php`

```
<?php

final class TestObject {
    private $price = 0;

    public function setPrice($amount) {
        $this->price = $amount;
    }

    public function getPrice() {
        return $this->price;
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that additional files need to follow the PSR-0 standard - and in the case of this, the `TestObject` class needed to be in a file with the same name, e.g. `TestObject.php`

Comment: URL is deprecated.